# Kotlin: Programing is printing kotlin.unit

Tags: kotlin

My Kotlin Class will run but it prints out the words: kotlin.Unit. What do I need to change?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var myDuck = Duck()
    println(myDuck.quack())
}
class Duck() {
    fun quack () {
        println("Quack, Quack, Quack")
    }
}
```

Comment: Just call myDuck.quack() instead of println(myDuck.quack())

Answer (score 4):

It is printing that because you are printing the return type of a function that does not return any value. If you are familiar with other languages it is the same as having a `void` return type.

In kotlin a funtion without a return type returns  a [`unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/) type, and so when you print the return value of `Duck::quack` you are printing the string value of a `Unit` value.

The simplest solution is to not print the return value of `Duck::quack`; however, if you would like the `prinlt` to print the return of `Duck::quak`, it needs to return a useful value. For examle:

```kotlin
class Duck() {
    fun quack(): String {
        return "Quack, Quack, Quack"
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var myDuck = Duck()

    println(myDuck.quack())
}
```

or more idiomatically:

```kotlin
class Duck() {
    val quack: String = "Quack, Quack. Quack"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var myDuck = Duck()

    println(myDuck.quack)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's anought to call

```
    myDuck.quack()
```

wich has already *println* inside. Calling println(myDuck.quack()) prints type of myDuck.quack because it doesn't return any value.

Answer (score 0):

1.prints "kotlin.Unit" if you don't specify the type

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var myDuck = Duck()
    println(myDuck.quack())
}
class Duck():String {
    fun quack () {
        return "Quack, Quack, Quack"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to specify the return type of `quack()`? A `Duck` being a `String` doesn't make much sense here...

Answer (score 0):

**Also as shortly:**

```
fun main() {        
        println(Duck.quack())
    }

class Duck() {
    fun quack () = "Quack, Quack, Quack"
    }
```